# How to use Ruby syntax in Bootstrap tooltip title?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-4

I need to show dynamic records in a bootstrap tooltip.
I am able to use HTML in bootstrap tooltip but getting error when I use Ruby code. My code sample is as follows

```
"<a data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='right' data-html='true' data-original-title='
<h5>Title for #{label} file</h5>
<% users.each do |user| %>
    <div class=row>
        <div class=col-sm-6>
            #{user.name}
        </div>
        <div class=col-sm-6>
            <div class=rectangle id=#{status}>
                #{user.id)}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<%end%>'
href='/link'>Right tooltip</a>"
```

Everything works fine in this code if `users.each` loop is not used.

If it is used I'm getting the error

> NameError: undefined local variable or method 'user'.

While users have all records in it. The issue is it is not recognizing Ruby syntax.

Comment: how do you use that tooltip code?

Comment: This code is written in a method in a decorator and that method gets called in view as a value of <td>

Comment: Why you want to do such mysterious work?

Comment: @krishnar on link hover, I want to show it's details. If I use modal on it's hover then it does not redirect on click. That's why I decided to use tooltip. It's perfect for my requirement if ruby code supports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and that method gets called in view as a value of `<td>`

That looks like this, I imagine?

```
<td><%= decorator.bootstrap_html %></td>
```

So you have to pass it through ERB yourself. Something like this:

```
<td><%= ERB.new(decorator.bootstrap_html).result(binding) %></td>
```

Or probably it's the decorator that should do this. Just make sure your `users` is in the scope and replace `#{user.name}` with a proper ERB's `<%= user.name %>`.

Comment: ERB.new(decorator.bootstrap_html).result(binding) amazing solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
ERB.new("<a data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='right' data-html='true' data-original-title='
<h5>Title for #{label} file</h5>
<% users.each do |user|  @user = user %>
    <div class=row>
        <div class=col-sm-6>
            <%= @user.name %>
        </div>
        <div class=col-sm-6>
            <div class=rectangle id=#{@user.status}>
                <%= @user.id %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<%end%>'
href='/link'>Right tooltip</a>").result(binding)
```

This is the working code.